# Как ускорить алгоритм поиска числа каталана?

Tags: c++

Есть очень медленный код поиска остатка числа каталана. Нужно найти остаток n-ого числа каталана по модулю m. n не превышает 10000, m не превышает 10 в 9 степение. Если ввести число 10000, то оно считает секунд 10, а тайм лимит - 1 секунда. Пытался делать через формулу с делениями факториалов, но там если если искать остатки множителей для факториала, то результат неправильный.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> kat_nums(10002, -1);
#pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:300000000")

int katalans_num(int k, int m)
{
    if (kat_nums[k] != -1) return kat_nums[k];
        else
        {
        unsigned long long sum = 0;
        if (k == 0) return 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            sum += katalans_num(i, m)%m * katalans_num(k - i - 1, m)%m;
        }
        kat_nums[k] = sum % m;
        return sum%m;
    }
}

int main()
{
    kat_nums[0] = 1;
    int n, m, res;
    cin >> n >> m;
    cout << katalans_num(n, m) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Считайте числа Каталана через биномиальные коэффициенты: [Числа Каталана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Comment: мемоизация будет проще.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy она есть, и даже с ней работает очень медленно

Comment: Да, действительно.

Comment: У меня ваш код укладывается в 0.9с.

Comment: Если можно ограничится только простыми m (или m взаимно простыми с {2...n}), то обратный элемент по модулю m всегда существует и легко рассчитывается. Тогда расчёт `(2n)!/(n+1)!/n!`, очевидно, предпочтительнее.

Comment: P.S. Или, скажем, если m всегда степень 10 или 2, то тоже можно из n! сократить все степени 2 и 5, хоть и несколько сложнее. В общем виде, не уверен, что разложение m на множители и сокращение дроби произведений на степени этих множителей до умножения и деления окажется простым и шустрым.

Comment: А ты в релизе запускаешь или в дебаге?

Comment: @Qwertiy в дебаге. а разве что, есть разница ?

Comment: @Ultra_Dog, в скорости работы stl - в разы.

Comment: Формула для числа через биномиальные коэффициенты. Все множители разлагаем на простые. Умножения и деления делаем в виде степеней простых. Знаменатель пропадает. Финальное умножение делаем по модулю. Почти линейное время.

Comment: Действительно. Тут ведь не нужно считать остаток после каждой операции, поэтому можно и не париться с делением, а просто использовать "линейное решето Эратосфена" и решить задачу за NlogN.

Answer (score 5):

[Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1254743/394856) немного слукавил, когда сказал, что делить по модулю нельзя. На самом деле деление по модулю вполне определено для делителей взаимно простых с самим модулем как умножение на обратный к делителю элемент в кольце.

Для того чтобы разделить `N` на `7` по модулю `20`, если `N % 20 = 5` (например, `N = 105`), нужно найти `7^(-1) = 3 (mod 20)` и просто вычислить `((N % mod) * D^(-1)) % mod`, что при подстановке тождественно `(5 * 3) % 20 = 15`. Проверим результат реальным делением `105` на `7`: `105 / 7 = 15`, `15 % 20 = 15`. Таким образом, мы действительно "разделили" остаток `R` на некоторое число `D` и получили новый остаток `R'`, причем это произошло корректно для каждого числа в кольце, соответствующего данному остатку `R`, которое делится на `D`.

При этом, можно утверждать, что делить на не взаимно простые делители нельзя, так как результат либо не будет существовать, либо будет не единственным. Доказывать это, как и свой прошлый абзац я не буду, послушайте какой-нибудь нормальный курс модульной арифметики, если хотите подробностей.

Таким образом, мы можем делить заданное остатком число на любое взаимно простое с модулем. Чтобы делить заданное остатком число вообще на любое, просто будем хранить степени простых, входящих в разложение модуля, вдобавок к его остатку (точнее к особому остатку).

Если конкретно, то давайте представим наше число `N` как `(A^a * B^b * ... * D^d) * R`, где `A, B, ..., D` - простые, входящие в разложение модуля, а `R` - произведение всех остальных степеней простых. Тогда остаток от `N` мы можем вычислить просто перемножив остатки степеней `A^a, B^b, ... D^d` между собой и с остатком от `R`. Получается, что поддерживая степени `a, b, ..., d` и остаток от произведения `R`, мы можем в любой момент получить остаток от текущего значения `N`. Очевидно, что можно поддерживать степени при умножении и делении и `R` при умножении. Но так как `R` мы будем делить только на некоторое `D`, в разложение которого не входят простые из разложения `M`, то `D` - взаимно просто с модулем, а значит, для деления мы можем просто умножить `R` на обратное к `D`, что не составляет никаких проблем.

То есть число `105` по модулю `20` мы представили бы как `[{2: 0, 5: 1}, (105 / (2^0 * 5^1)) % 20]`. Таким образом, при делении на `15`, мы можем сначала разделить наше число `N = 105` разделить на `5`, которое входит в разложение модуля, а потом разделить остаток на `3`, которое уже взаимно просто с модулем. Тогда мы получаем число `[{2: 0, 5: 1 - 1}, (1 * 3^(-1)) % 20] = 7 (mod 20)`.

Если использовать данный способ, то в общем случае асимптотики операций при их оптимальной реализации такие:

- `Init(N, M)`: Инициализация объекта числом `N` по модулю `M`: `O(sqrt(M) + Mult(N))`.
- `Mult(N)`: Умножение рассматриваемого числа на `N` по рассматриваемому модулю `M`: `O(log(N) + log(M))`
- `Div(N)`: Деление рассматриваемого числа на `N` по рассматриваемому модулю `M`: `O(log(N) + log(M))`
- `Get()`: Получение остатка рассматриваемого числа по рассматриваемому модулю `M` после `K` операций умножения: `O(log(M) * log(K))` или около того

Так как существует формула `C(n) = C(n - 1) * (4n - 2) / (n + 1)`, то общая сложность алгоритма составит `O(N * (log(N) + log(M)) + sqrt(M))`, если ничего не путаю

Код:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
#include "algorithm"

#define ll long long

using namespace std;

struct Number
{
    int M;
    vector<int> M_factors;
    vector<int> M_degrees;
    vector<int> X_degrees;
    ll remainder;
    int phi;

    void factor(int n, vector<int>& factors, vector<int>& degrees)
    {
        int x = n;
        for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (x % i == 0)
            {
                factors.push_back(i);
                degrees.push_back(0);

                while (x % i == 0)
                {
                    degrees[degrees.size() - 1]++;
                    x /= i;
                }
            }
        }

        if (x > 1)
        {
            factors.push_back(x);
            degrees.push_back(1);
        }
    }

    int phi_function(vector<int>& factors, vector<int>& degrees)
    {
        int res = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < factors.size(); i++)
        {
            int z = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < degrees[i]; j++)
                z *= factors[i];
            res *= z - z / factors[i];
        }
        return res;
    }

    int reverse_element(ll x)
    {
        ll res = 1, pow = phi - 1;

        while (pow) //101
        {
            if (pow & 1)
                res = (res * x) % M;
            x = (x * x) % M;
            pow >>= 1;
        }

        return res;
    }

    Number(int mod)
    {
        M = mod;
        factor(mod, M_factors, M_degrees);
        X_degrees = vector<int>(M_factors.size(), 0);
        remainder = 1;
        phi = phi_function(M_factors, M_degrees);
    }

    Number operator *=(int x)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < M_factors.size(); i++)
        {
            while (x % M_factors[i] == 0)
            {
                X_degrees[i]++; 
                x /= M_factors[i];
            }
        }
            
        remainder = (remainder * x) % M;

        return *this;
    }

    Number operator /=(int x)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < M_factors.size(); i++)
        {
            while (x % M_factors[i] == 0)
            {
                X_degrees[i]--;
                x /= M_factors[i];
            }
        }

        remainder = (remainder * reverse_element(x)) % M;

        return *this;
    }

    // Как оказалось, в итоге я не могу оптимизировать get() так, как изначально предполагал. 
    // В моей реализации его асимптотика составляет O(N*log(N)), где N - количество выполненных умножений
    // Однако используя бинарное возведение в степень можно улучшить до O(log(M) * log(N)), где N - количество выполненных умножений 
    int get() 
    {
        ll res = remainder;
        for (int i = 0; i < M_factors.size(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < X_degrees[i]; j++)
                res = (res * M_factors[i]) % M;
        return res;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    Number x(m);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        x *= 4 * i - 2;
        x /= i + 1;
    }

    cout << x.get() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо [Станиславу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254719#comment2205159_1254888) за проверку и измерение скорости работы программы: `n=10000, m=1000000000 -> 0.010s`

Comment: Вы в итоге получите китайскую теорему об остатках. Насколько я помню восстановить результат там очень сложно без длинной арифметики. Да, код нужен.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy никого я не получу). Остаток восстанавливается элементарно: (p1^q1 * p2^q1 * ... * pk^qk * r) % mod, где p - простые в разложении модуля, q - их степени в рассматриваемом числе, r - остаток при делении произведения взаимно простых с mod множителей  на mod. Да и сама кто не так уж и сложно вычисляется - нужно просто решить диофантово уравнение N - 1 раз, где N - количество модулей. Код вечером добавлю, окей.

Comment: Да рассудит нас код.

Comment: А вы правы, это можно довести до ума.

Comment: Ошибка: `$ echo 5 10000 | ./a.out` -> `42`, `echo 5 100000 | ./a.out` -> `6250`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо,  исправил

Comment: Считает правильно.

Comment: `n=10000, m=1000000000` -> `0.010s`. Время отличное.

Answer (score 4):

Считать будем по формуле `C(0) = 1, C(n) = (2(2n-1) / (n+1)) * C(n-1)`.
Все множители из формулы разложим на простые (решето Эратосфена) и запомним их степени. При умножении чисел степени их простых складываются, при делении вычитаются.

После всех умножений и делений должны остаться только неотрицательные степени. Простые возводим в эти степени и перемножаем по модулю. Это первый раз где модуль используется.

Сложность оценить точно не берусь. Надеюсь что где-то в районе `O(nlogn)`:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2 catalan-primes.cpp

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> make_sieve(int n) {
    std::vector<int> sieve(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sieve[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i * i < n; ++i) {
        if (sieve[i] == i) { // is prime
            for (int j = i * i; j < n; j += i) {
                sieve[j] = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return sieve;
}

void add(const std::vector<int> &sieve, int n, std::vector<int> &powers) {
    while (n > 1) {
        const int p = sieve[n];
        ++powers[p];
        n /= p;
    }
}

void negate(std::vector<int> &powers) {
    for (int &v : powers) {
        v = -v;
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned n;
    uint64_t m;
    while (std::cin >> n >> m) {
        std::vector<int> sieve = make_sieve(std::max(3u, 2 * n));

        std::vector<int> powers(2 * n, 0);

        // denominators
        for (unsigned i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            add(sieve, i + 1, powers);
        }
        negate(powers);

        // numerators
        for (unsigned i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            add(sieve, 2, powers);
            add(sieve, 2 * i - 1, powers);
        }

        uint64_t product = 1;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < 2 * n; ++i) {
            assert(powers[i] >= 0);
            for (int j = 0; j < powers[i]; ++j) {
                product = (product * i) % m;
            }
        }
        std::cout << product << '\n';
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2 catalan-primes.cpp
> $ time echo 10000 1000000000 | ./a.out 
> 287516640
>
> real  0m0.003s
> user  0m0.004s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Среди всей этой математики в ответах не хватает двух алгоритмов, один более известный [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Факториал#Разложение_на_простые_множители](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8), второй менее [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Качающийся_факториал](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB), которые позволяют эффективно следовать совету "Считайте числа Каталана через биномиальные коэффициенты" от @Stanislav Volodarskiy

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

#if !defined(prime_t)
typedef int32_t prime_t;
#endif
typedef int32_t module_t;

template <typename T, class Pcont, class Fcont>
void factorize(const Pcont &primes, T n,  Fcont &factors)
{
    assert(primes.back() >= n - n/3); // Проверка на дурацкие ошибки

    auto pf = factors.begin();
    for(const auto p : primes) {
        if(n <= 1)
            break;

        T f = 0;

        while(n%p == 0) {
            n /= p;
            f++;
        }

        *pf++ += f;
    }
    assert(n == 1);
}

template <typename T, class Pcont, class Fcont>
void factorial_factorize(const Pcont &primes, T n,  Fcont &factors)
{
    assert(primes.back() >= n - n/3); // Проверка на дурацкие ошибки

    auto pf = factors.begin();
    for(const auto p : primes) {
        if(n < p)
            break;

        T x = n;
        T f = 0;

        do {
            x = x/p;
            f += x;
        } while(x >= p);

        *pf++ += f;
    }
}

// https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Качающийся_факториал
template <typename T, class Pcont, class Fcont>
void swinging_factorial_factorize(const Pcont &primes, T n,  Fcont &factors)
{
    assert(primes.back() >= n - n/3); // Проверка на дурацкие ошибки

    auto pf = factors.begin();
    for(const auto p : primes) {
        if(n < p)
            break;

        T x = n;
        T f = 0;

        do {
            x = x/p;
            f += (x&1);
        } while(x >= p);

        *pf++ += f;
    }
}

template <class Pcont, typename TP, typename TM, typename DT = int64_t>
TM katlan_num(const Pcont &ps, TP n, TM m)
{
        // C(n) = binomial(2n, n) - binomial(2n, n - 1) =
        //      = (2*n)!/( (n!)^2 * (n + 1) )
        //      = swinging_factorial(2*n)/(n + 1)
    std::vector<TP> f(ps.size(), 0);

    #if 0
            // (n!)^2 * (n + 1)
        factorial_factorize(ps, n, f);
        for(auto &&x : f) {
            x = 2*x;
        }
        factorize(ps, n + 1, f);
            // 1/(n!)^2 * (n + 1)
        for(auto &&x : f) {
            x = -x;
        }
            // (2*n)!/( (n!)^2 * (n + 1) )
        factorial_factorize(ps, 2*n, f);
    #else
        factorize(ps, n + 1, f);
        for(auto &&x : f) {
            x = -x;
        }
        swinging_factorial_factorize(ps, 2*n, f);
    #endif

    DT product = 1;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ps.size(); i++) {
        auto p = ps[i];

        assert(f[i] >= 0);
        for(auto j = f[i]; j > 0; --j) {
            product = (product*p)%m;
        }
    }

    return product;
}

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

#if __cplusplus+0 <= 201703 || defined(DONT_CE_PRIMES)
    #define PRIMES_CONSTEXP_
#else
    #define PRIMES_CONSTEXP_ constexpr
    #define CE_PRIMES 1
#endif

template<class Pcont, class Scont>
PRIMES_CONSTEXP_ Pcont
primes_impl_(size_t n, size_t reserve)
{
    Pcont primes;
    primes.reserve(reserve);
    primes.push_back(2);
    primes.push_back(3);

    Scont sieve((n + 1)/2);
    auto pp = sieve.begin() + 1;
    size_t p = 3;                       // 2*(pp - sieve.begin()) + 1;
    size_t jp2 = 4;                     // p*p/2;

    while(jp2 < sieve.size()) {
        do {
            sieve[jp2] = true;
            jp2 += p;
        } while(jp2 < sieve.size());

        pp = std::find(pp + 1, sieve.end(), false);

        p = 2*(pp - sieve.begin()) + 1;
        primes.push_back(p);
        jp2 = p*(p/2);
    }

    while((pp = std::find(pp + 1, sieve.end(), false)) != sieve.end()) {
        primes.push_back(2*(pp - sieve.begin()) + 1);
    }

    return primes;
}

#ifdef CE_PRIMES
    template<typename T, size_t N>
    class ce_vector_array_ : public std::array<T, N>
    {
        size_t m_size;

    public:
        constexpr ce_vector_array_(size_t n = 0) :
            std::array<T, N>{},
            m_size{n}
        { ; }

        constexpr ce_vector_array_(std::initializer_list<T> l) :
            std::array<T, N>{},
            m_size{0}
        { 
            for(auto i : l) {
                (*this)[m_size++] = i;
            }
        }

        constexpr void push_back(const T value) {
            (*this)[m_size++] = value;
        }

        constexpr void reserve(size_t n) {
            assert(n <= (*this).size());
        }

        constexpr size_t size() const {
            return m_size;
        }
    };


    template<int N, typename T=unsigned>
    constexpr auto
    ce_primes(void)
    {
        static_assert(N >= 3, "N >= 3");
        constexpr const auto collected{primes_impl_<
                                        ce_vector_array_<T, N>,
                                        ce_vector_array_<bool, (N + 1)/2>
                                    >(N, 0) };
        std::array<T, collected.size()> primes{};

        for(size_t i = 0; i < collected.size(); i++) {
            primes[i] = collected[i];
        }
        return primes;
    }
#endif

//#include <bit>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T=unsigned>
std::vector<T>
primes(T n)
{
    // Чебышев: 0.92129 <= m <= pi(x)/(x/ln(x)) <= M <= 1.10555
    // Конечно, на бесконечности.
    size_t reserve = 2 + 1.2*n/std::log(n);
                                        // По первым 10⁹, с "запасом" 6..14%
    //size_t reserve = 6 + 1.8*n/std::bit_width((size_t)n); // constexpr, C++20
    //size_t reserve = 6 + 1.8*n/std::log2p1((size_t)n); // n4849, clang
                                        // По первым 10⁹, с "запасом" 3..19%
    auto ps = primes_impl_<std::vector<T>, std::vector<bool> >(n, reserve);

    assert(ps.size() <= reserve);
    assert(n < 200 || reserve <= 1.2*ps.size());

    ps.shrink_to_fit();
    
    return ps;
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    prime_t n;
    module_t m;
    #ifdef USE_CE_PRIMES
        auto ps = ce_primes<32767, prime_t>();
    #endif

    while(std::cin >> n >> m) {
        #ifndef USE_CE_PRIMES
            auto ps = primes(2*n);
        #endif
        std::cout << katlan_num(ps, n, m) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Асимптотическая сложность выходит `n*ln(ln(n))`, а практическая вообще неприличная, типа, 51 мкс, если таблицу простых вычислять динамически, каждый раз:

```
$ clang++-mp-11 -std=c++20 -Wall -g -DNDEBUG -Ofast -march=native t_katlan_Serge3leo.cpp
$ yes '10000 1000000' | head -10000 | (time ./a.out) | sort -u
real    0m0.713s
user    0m0.508s
sys 0m0.011s
516640
```

И 27 мкс, если простые числа получать во время компиляции (C++20 constexpr):

```
$ clang++-mp-11 -std=c++20 -Wall -g -DUSE_CE_PRIMES -Dprime_t=int16_t -DNDEBUG -Ofast -march=native t_katlan_Serge3leo.cpp
$ yes '10000 1000000' | head -10000 | (time ./a.out) | sort -u
real    0m0.437s
user    0m0.265s
sys 0m0.010s
516640
```

P.S.
Однако, хотя он и работает гораздо шустрее, но учитывая весьма существенную вероятность того, что `katlan_num(ps, n, m)` кратен `m`, возможно это и не самый лучший способ.

Comment: Очень крутое дополнение. Я не знал обоих фактов. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы написали нормальный код, который у меня работает за 0.5с.

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2 original.cpp 
> $ time echo 10000 1000000000 | ./a.out 
> 500322272
>
> real  0m0.477s
> user  0m0.476s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Сложность вашего варианта `O(n^2)`. Если считать через биномиальные коэффициенты рекуррентно, то будет такая же сложность.

Сперва мне показалось что биномиальные коэффициенты можно вычислить через факториалы за линейное время. Но там деление, которое не уложить в модулярную арифметику *(см. NB)*, а без модулей всё сильно замедляется и толку от линейного числа умножений нет, если каждое умножение требует более чем линейного времени.

*NB: деление отлично делается по модулю: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1254888/416121.*

В конце концов я вернулся к вашему варианту, убрал переполнения, изменил порядок вычисления чисел, сократил внутренний цикл в два раза. Время снизилось в полтора раза. Этого хватит?

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2 catalan.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int n;
    uint64_t m;
    if (!(std::cin >> n >> m)) {
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector<uint64_t> catalan(n + 1);
    catalan[0] = 1;
    for (int k = 1; k <= n; ++k) {
        uint64_t s = 0;
        if ((k - 1) % 2 == 0) {
            const int i = (k - 1) / 2;
            s = catalan[i] * catalan[i] % m;
        }
        for (int i = 0, j = k - 1; i < j; ++i, --j)
        {
            s = (s + 2 * catalan[i] * catalan[j]) % m;
        }
        catalan[k] = s;
    }
    std::cout << catalan[n] << "\n";
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2 catalan.cpp 
> $ time echo 10000 1000000000 | ./a.out 
> 287516640
>
> real  0m0.289s
> user  0m0.288s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```